# PHP - echo skipping text

Tags: php, domdocument

So I have this simple code:

```
 foreach($items as $index=>$item)
 {
   echo "<strong>Item " . $index+1 . " (" . $item[0]->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue .")</strong>";
 }
```

`$items` has only 1 item for now, which is an array of DOMDocument data from an XML file.
`$item[0]->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue` is "purchase";

However, the HTML printed is:
`1 (purchase)`

Why is this, and how can I correct it?

Thanks,
~Hom

Comment: Have you tried: echo "<strong>Item " . ((int)$index+1) . " (";

Comment: Awesome! I posted it as an answer so that you can mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $index may or may not be a number, so use the (int) in front to convert it.  Next, put your mathematical operations in parentheses to avoid trying to "add" strings to the sum.

```
foreach($items as $index=>$item)
{
  echo "<strong>Item " . ((int)$index+1) . " (" . $item[0]->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue .")</strong>";
}
```